# RegEx pattern to scrape data from HTML Tags

Tags: html, regex

What will be the regex pattern to match this pattern where inside header tag any number of attributes like `id`, `class` can be there and zero or more number of strong tag can be inside the header tag? I want to match the pattern which follows:

1. Any HTML header (h1-h5)
2. Any attributes can be present inside header tag.
3. zero or more number of strong tag can be present.

```
<h5 id="some_id"><strong><strong><strong>SOME_TEXT</strong></strong></strong></h5>
```

Comment: Parsing HTML with regex is [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3832970). Why do you want to do that with a regex?

Comment: Which language? Also: [H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Also, I think you're mixing up the terms [*Attributes*](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_attributes.asp) and [*Elements*](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_elements.asp)

Comment: Using python, what will the best way to get SOME_TEXT(see html code above) inside any header tag that follows the above mentioned pattern?

Comment: Use BeautifulSoup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
match = re.search(r"<(h[1-5])\b(?:[^>]|>[<\s])*>([^<]+)(?:[^<]|<(?!/\1))*</\1>", 
    subject, re.IGNORECASE)
if match:
    result = match.group(2)
else:
    result = ""
```

I'll add a regex101 in a sec to show how this works.

Here it is: https://regex101.com/r/du8PCn/1 (it's Group 2 that matches).

EDIT: I don't know much about Python, but I believe you'll need to use `re.findall` or `re.finditer` above if you're matching an html string with a number of headings in it (instead of `re.search`).

Comment: Thanks for the pattern. I did some modifications and made it work.